# mellanox connectx-3 (cx312a) link down though light is blinking

Tags: truenas, sfp, mellanox

I have a system running TrueNas Scale. For some odd reasons, the system does not see the link is up even though dmesg reports it up and the light is blinking on the port. I'm not sure if this is optic's compatibility because I am using a Ericson's one (recognized in Juniper). What is also odd is advertised auto-negotation is off. Here is some commands that I use to troubleshoot. I also tried both ports on the NIC.

Here is dmesg

```
admin@truenas[~]$ sudo dmesg | grep mlx    
[    1.865599] mlx4_core: Mellanox ConnectX core driver v4.0-0
[    1.866114] mlx4_core: Initializing 0000:01:00.0
[    1.866639] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.864380] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0: DMFS high rate steer mode is: disabled performance optimized steering
[    8.865246] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0: 63.008 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth (8.0 GT/s PCIe x8 link)
[    8.943401] mlx4_en: Mellanox ConnectX HCA Ethernet driver v4.0-0
[    8.943890] mlx4_en 0000:01:00.0: Activating port:1
[    8.947954] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 1: Using 8 TX rings
[    8.948294] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 1: Using 8 RX rings
[    8.948836] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 1: Initializing port
[    8.949441] mlx4_en 0000:01:00.0: registered PHC clock
[    8.950038] mlx4_en 0000:01:00.0: Activating port:2
[    8.951205] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[    8.953510] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 2: Using 8 TX rings
[    8.954069] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 2: Using 8 RX rings
[    8.954840] mlx4_en: 0000:01:00.0: Port 2: Initializing port
[    8.980259] <mlx4_ib> mlx4_ib_add: mlx4_ib: Mellanox ConnectX InfiniBand driver v4.0-0
[    8.982100] <mlx4_ib> mlx4_ib_add: counter index 2 for port 1 allocated 1
[    8.982215] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0d1: renamed from eth0
[    8.982567] <mlx4_ib> mlx4_ib_add: counter index 3 for port 2 allocated 1
[   11.659376] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Up
[  185.391704] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Down
[  257.903512] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Up
[ 1486.106437] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Down
[ 1524.842156] mlx4_core 0000:01:00.0: MLX4_CMD_MAD_IFC Get Module ID attr(ff60) port(1) i2c_addr(50) offset(0) size(1): Response Mad Status(31c) - cable is not connected
[ 1591.308231] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Up
[ 2026.000939] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Down
[ 2047.724983] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Up
[ 3657.633665] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Down
[ 3684.070133] mlx4_en: enp1s0d1: Link Up
[ 4577.747372] mlx4_en: enp1s0d1: Link Down
[ 4631.805428] mlx4_en: enp1s0: Link Up
```

Here is ethtool

```
admin@truenas[~]$ sudo ethtool enp1s0
Settings for enp1s0:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   1000baseX/Full
                            10000baseCR/Full
                            10000baseSR/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseX/Full
                            10000baseCR/Full
                            10000baseSR/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: FIBRE
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)
                               link ifdown
    Link detected: no
```

Here is ethtool for optics:

```
admin@truenas[~]$ sudo ethtool -m enp1s0
    Identifier                                : 0x03 (SFP)
    Extended identifier                       : 0x04 (GBIC/SFP defined by 2-wire interface ID)
    Connector                                 : 0x07 (LC)
    Transceiver codes                         : 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Transceiver type                          : 10G Ethernet: 10G Base-SR
    Encoding                                  : 0x06 (64B/66B)
    BR, Nominal                               : 10300MBd
    Rate identifier                           : 0x00 (unspecified)
    Length (SMF,km)                           : 0km
    Length (SMF)                              : 0m
    Length (50um)                             : 80m
    Length (62.5um)                           : 30m
    Length (Copper)                           : 0m
    Length (OM3)                              : 300m
    Laser wavelength                          : 850nm
    Vendor name                               : FINISAR CORP.
    Vendor OUI                                : 00:90:65
    Vendor PN                                 : FTLX8571D3BCL-ER
    Vendor rev                                : A
    Option values                             : 0x00 0x1a
    Option                                    : RX_LOS implemented
    Option                                    : TX_FAULT implemented
    Option                                    : TX_DISABLE implemented
    BR margin, max                            : 0%
    BR margin, min                            : 0%
    Vendor SN                                 : AP3193K
    Date code                                 : 130127
    Optical diagnostics support               : Yes
    Laser bias current                        : 8.036 mA
    Laser output power                        : 0.6284 mW / -2.02 dBm
    Receiver signal average optical power     : 0.7003 mW / -1.55 dBm
    Module temperature                        : 41.64 degrees C / 106.95 degrees F
    Module voltage                            : 3.2852 V
    Alarm/warning flags implemented           : Yes
    Laser bias current high alarm             : Off
    Laser bias current low alarm              : Off
    Laser bias current high warning           : Off
    Laser bias current low warning            : Off
    Laser output power high alarm             : Off
    Laser output power low alarm              : Off
    Laser output power high warning           : Off
    Laser output power low warning            : Off
    Module temperature high alarm             : Off
    Module temperature low alarm              : Off
    Module temperature high warning           : Off
    Module temperature low warning            : Off
    Module voltage high alarm                 : Off
    Module voltage low alarm                  : Off
    Module voltage high warning               : Off
    Module voltage low warning                : Off
    Laser rx power high alarm                 : Off
    Laser rx power low alarm                  : Off
    Laser rx power high warning               : Off
    Laser rx power low warning                : Off
    Laser bias current high alarm threshold   : 13.200 mA
    Laser bias current low alarm threshold    : 4.000 mA
    Laser bias current high warning threshold : 12.600 mA
    Laser bias current low warning threshold  : 5.000 mA
    Laser output power high alarm threshold   : 1.0000 mW / 0.00 dBm
    Laser output power low alarm threshold    : 0.2512 mW / -6.00 dBm
    Laser output power high warning threshold : 0.7943 mW / -1.00 dBm
    Laser output power low warning threshold  : 0.3162 mW / -5.00 dBm
    Module temperature high alarm threshold   : 78.00 degrees C / 172.40 degrees F
    Module temperature low alarm threshold    : -13.00 degrees C / 8.60 degrees F
    Module temperature high warning threshold : 73.00 degrees C / 163.40 degrees F
    Module temperature low warning threshold  : -8.00 degrees C / 17.60 degrees F
    Module voltage high alarm threshold       : 3.7000 V
    Module voltage low alarm threshold        : 2.9000 V
    Module voltage high warning threshold     : 3.6000 V
    Module voltage low warning threshold      : 3.0000 V
    Laser rx power high alarm threshold       : 1.0000 mW / 0.00 dBm
    Laser rx power low alarm threshold        : 0.0100 mW / -20.00 dBm
    Laser rx power high warning threshold     : 0.7943 mW / -1.00 dBm
    Laser rx power low warning threshold      : 0.0158 mW / -18.01 dBm
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. I can just assign the IP to the interface and bring it up to use.